# Frobenius norm of a matrix

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

I know that Frobenius norm of a matrix A is equal to the square root of the trace of (A*conjugate transpose(A)). But how do I prove it mathematically?

Comment: What definition of the Frobenius norm are you starting from?  Also, what have you tried?

Comment: Just do the 2 by 2 and then 3 by 3 cases, write out matrices with numbers or symbols, this is not difficult. This particular one works with rectangular matrices, so do a 2 by 3 and then a 3 by 2 example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Presumably, you have the entry-wise definition,
$$
\|A\|_F^2 = \sum_{i,j} |a_{ij}|^2
$$
In order to get to this from the trace of the product $AA^*$, use the summation definition of matrix multiplication:
$$
[AB](i,j) = \sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}b_{kj}
$$
and of the trace:
$$
\text{trace}(A) = \sum_{\ell = 1}^n a_{\ell \ell}
$$

Comment: Can I write trace(AB) as ![formula][1]
[1]: https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=trace(AB)%26space%3B%3D%26space%3B%5Csum_%7Bi%3D1%7D%5E%7Bn%7D%5Csum_%7Bj%3D1%7D%5E%7Bm%7Da_%7Bij%7Db_%7Bji%7D%22%20target%3D%22_blank%22%3E%3Cimg%20src%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Flatex.codecogs.com%2Fgif.latex%3Ftrace(AB)%26space%3B%3D%26space%3B%5Csum_%7Bi%3D1%7D%5E%7Bn%7D%5Csum_%7Bj%3D1%7D%5E%7Bm%7Da_%7Bij%7Db_%7Bji%7D%22%20title%3D%22trace(AB)%20%3D%20%5Csum_%7Bi%3D1%7D%5E%7Bn%7D%5Csum_%7Bj%3D1%7D%5E%7Bm%7Da_%7Bij%7Db_%7Bji%7D%22

If yes, how do I use this and the two definitions you stated to prove?

Comment: If you already know that
$$
\text{trace}(AB) = \sum_{i,j = 1}^n a_{ij}b_{ji}
$$
then all you need to do is plug in $A = A$ and $B = A^*$.  My answer is a way of deriving that formula, in this instance.

Comment: If I replace A with A and B with ![formula][1], the RHS will become ![another][2]. Isn't this wrong? (as this is not the definition of Frobenius norm)

[1]: https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=A%5E%7B*%7D
[2]: https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=%5Csum_%7Bi%2Cj%3D1%7D%5E%7Bn%7Da_%7Bij%7Da_%7Bji%7D

Comment: Please format your text readably.  For example, what I have written above is
$$
\,
$$
`\text{trace}(AB) = \sum_{i,j}^n a_{ij}b_{ji}`

Comment: I figured out how to prove using the definitions you stated. Thanks for your input.